# Maximum idle time before web chat should be disconnected

Tags: user-behavior

For user experience what is the standard wait time a live chat agent should wait for the customer to respond before displaying a message and disconnecting the idle web chat session?

Comment: Monika, did you got the anwer to your question?

Answer (score 2):

Given that it is a web-based chatting experience, there are multiple things that has to be taken into account here

- Whether user has **initiated** the chat? ,
- Whether user has **focussed or typed** into that chatbox?,
- After **showing the intent** to chat, has the user gone to another tab or page and hasn't returned for a while?,
- Whether user has **asked a question** and your agent has asked to **wait** for sometime?,
- Whether user **has been asked a question** and to revert with something?

Not a comprehensive list of scenarios by any means, but it just goes to suggest that you can't simply go by a **single-number** of *standard wait time*.

I would suggest following

1)  If user has initiated an action, let the user be **introduced** to the agent first. Let the agent ask a couple of questions to verify the user if required (most likely not required if the user is already registered with you).

2)  Once user has asked a question and still waiting (can be measure by his scroll area and frequency of coming back to the chat window), keep the chat in a **RED** conversation mode.

3)  If user has asked a question but is not actively looking for reply (measured in a same way as above), keep the conversation in **RED** mode for a while (**10 minutes** - more than enough to cover for a tea or pee break) and bring it to a **YELLOW** mode.

4)  If the user is not showing any intent to look for a reply but has asked a question that must be replied to, then bring the conversation from **YELLOW** to **WHITE** mode in **2 hours** (Dormant mode, but active). But send an offline reply via email, sms, or any other kind of notification (better if your app has a notification mechanism).